# How to make two colums with css in one block?

Tags: html, css

I want to have two columns with this html. How can I make it?

```html
<div class="main-box">
 <div class="col_1">Column 1</div>
 <div class="col_1">Column 1</div>
 <div class="col_1">Column 1</div>
 <div class="col_2">Column 2</div>
 <div class="col_2">Column 2</div>
 <div class="col_2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't make two divs and put each col_n into correspoinding column. My html is generated by drupal and I don't know how to generate it in other way.

Comment: Surely your question should be asking how to modify the HTML?

Comment: Is `.main-box{column-count:2;}` not applicable to your HTML?

Comment: Css is editible for sure. But what I have is not a text, so column-count won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to float some of the elements:

```css
.col_1 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="col_1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col_1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col_1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col_2">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col_2">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col_2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```